# How to add one column to the another file

Tags: text-processing

suppose this is my file which its name is myFile1

```
1 10
2 20
3 30
4 40
5 50
6 60
```

know I want to add my another columns to this. This column is on the file which is myFile2.

```
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
```

. is there any way to add myFile2 to myFile1 to create this table :

```
1 10 10
2 20 11
3 30 12
4 40 13
5 50 14
6 60 15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paste` is pretty handy here but it'll punish you if the number of values is unequal:

```
$ paste -d' ' myFile{1,2}
1 10 10
2 20 11
3 30 12
4 40 13
5 50 14
6 60 15
 16
```

If you wanted to arbitrarily limit the lines used in the second file to the first, you can, it's just going to be a bit slower and use more RAM (not that it matters on such a small data set).

```
$ paste -d' ' myFile1 <(head -n$(cat myFile1 | wc -l) myFile2)
1 10 10
2 20 11
3 30 12
4 40 13
5 50 14
6 60 15
```

Comment: Oli I am sure you go to paradise.

Answer (score 1):

Could not resist adding the verbose option (python script)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

with open("file1") as l:
    l = [item.replace("\n", "") for item in l]

with open("file2") as l2:
    l2 = [item.replace("\n", "") for item in l2]

for item in [l[i]+" "+l2[i] for i in range(0, len(l))]:
    print(item)

>>> 
1 10 10
2 20 11
3 30 12
4 40 13
5 50 14
6 60 15
>>>
```

To immediately write the changes to file1, the code would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

with open("file1", "r") as l:
    l = [item.replace("\n", "") for item in l]

with open("file2", "r") as l2:
    l2 = [item.replace("\n", "") for item in l2]

with open("file1", "wt") as edit:
    for item in [l[i]+" "+l2[i] for i in range(0, len(l))]:
        edit.write(item+"\n")
```

In case there is also a possibility that file2 has *less* rows than file1, the code below takes care of correct adding of the column, and possible addition of more columns:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

with open("file1", "r") as l1:
    l1 = [item.replace("\n", "") for item in l1]

with open("file2", "r") as l2:
    l2 = [item.replace("\n", "") for item in l2]

for i in range(0, len(l1)):
    try:
        print(l1[i]+" "+l2[i])
    except IndexError:
        print(l1[i]+"  ")
```